# Select the Title- and Text area with the Office JavaScript API in PowerPoint

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I am trying to develop a basic Web Add-In for PowerPoint. What I want to do is to select either the Title Area or the Text Area from within the Office JS API, and then paste some text into these areas. However, I can't find anything on it in the Office JS API documentation.

In their tutorial, Microsoft includes a "Hello World" in the slide:

```
function insertText() {
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync('Hello World!',
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                showNotification("Error", asyncResult.error.message);
            }
        });
}
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/powerpoint-tutorial), but you first have to click on the Title Area before being able to do this (and I would like to do it with JavaScript)

Does anyone know if this possible at this moment? (I am a bit afraid it's not as Microsoft hasn't developed a specific PowerPoint Add-In, like they did for Excel and Word). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality that you've described isn't currently supported by the Office JavaScript APIs in PowerPoint. If you haven't already done so, I'd suggest that you upvote the [PowerPoint API feature request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33200554-powerpoint-api) on UserVoice (and/or consider submitting a new feature request there specifically for the capabilities that you've described).